# Reshape a 3d array into 5d array using pytorch

Tags: arrays, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, yolov4

I am trying to implement CAM in yolov4.
I am getting a feature map in the tensor shape torch.Size([1, 1083, 25]) and I need to convert it into shape torch.Size([1, 3, 13, 13, 10]). Do note that here the 13 * 13 is the stride and it can vary.

```
import torch
inputMap = torch.randn(1, 1083, 25)
torch.reshape(inputMap,(1,3,13,13,10))
```

And I am getting the below error :
----> 1 torch.reshape(inputMap,(1,3,13,13,10))

RuntimeError: shape '[1, 3, 13, 13, 10]' is invalid for input of size 27075

I assume the error is because the array is unable to fit in the new shape because of size difference. Please note that in torch.reshape, the 13 * 13 represents strides and it can vary. How can I get the ideal shape and reshape it for my requirements.

Comment: Why do you need to reshape it to that shape? Your first array has 27075 elements and so any reshape will have to have the product of that, too. 13*13*10*3 is only 5070 so you're a good deal off.

Comment: tensor shape is [1, 3, N, N, all_ids] This is the shape which I need. Actually need to pass it through a CAM function to visualise the heat maps in my detection result

Comment: Yes, but you have 27075 elements and are trying to fit `30xN^2` numbers into it. There is no N which satisfies this equation.

Comment: Any way I can convert it forcibly(even with loss of some information)?